# Update the record from query result

Tags: sql-server, mysql, postgresql, sqlite, sybase

Lets say I have a table X with following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE X( id INT PRIMARY KEY, field1 varchar(100), field2 int, field3 double);
```

Then I issue a query:

```
SELECT field1, field2 from X;
```

Let's say this query returned 10 records.

Is there a way to write a query to update the record #5 from the SELECT? What would the query will look like? Or I will have to include id in that query, somehow find its value in a record #5 and then use it in a query below?

Something like `UPDATE X SET field1 = 'def' WHERE...`.

I have a problem with the condition - what to write for the `WHERE` clause. I'm working with multiple DBMSes, so need a generic way if possible.

**More details:**

I can have a query like this:

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM X WHERE field3 = "abc";
```

or I can have a query like this:

```
SELECT X.field1, Y.field2 FROM X, Y WHERE X.pk = Y.pk AND X.field3 = "abc";
```

Let's say when I skip to record 5, X.field1 will show "abc". I want this field to be updated to "def". So I type "def" and skip to record 6. In both cases I want to update record 5 X.field1 of the resulting recordset.

As you can see I'm going by the records in a recordset (results of executing a query). I want to emulate what Access is doing.

Let's say I open the new form in Access and I base it on the query.
I re-arrange the field on the form to my liking and execute the form.
Then I go to display the record #5 in the form and then update a field.
This update is instantaneous, no matter the complexity of the query behind the form.

Answer (score 1):

> I actually want to emulate what Access is doing - update the record by its position in a recordset

Access, like most RDBMS systems uses key values to identify and update rows.  See:

> To add, edit, or delete a record, there must be a unique index on the
> record in the underlying data source. If not, a "Permission denied"
> error will occur on the AddNew, Delete, or Edit method call in a
> Microsoft Access workspace, or an "Invalid argument" error will occur
> on the Update call in an ODBCDirect workspace.

[Recordset.Update method (DAO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-update-method-dao)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Table t
WHERE   1 = 1
        AND EXISTS (Define criteria here)
```

The above is a select statement. It returns rows stored in a table.
To make this an UPDATE statement, use exactly the same syntax, except instead of using SELECT syntax, use UPDATE syntax.

```
UPDATE  t
SET     Column1 = 'SomeNeatValue'
        ,Column2 = 'AnotherNeatValue'
FROM    Table t
WHERE   1 = 1
        AND EXISTS (Define criteria here)
```

How you identify which records to select/update is on the developer. If you need assistance, I'd start at [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com) and bone up on query syntax.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132838/discussion-on-answer-by-mike-petri-update-the-record-from-query-result).